# Count of element in data.frame

Tags: r, count, group-by

I have data that illustrates hurricane tracks crossing through a series of "gates".  How would I code it to output the GateID, and the count of times that each GateID occurs in the total data frame?

```
track_id    day hour    month   year    rate    gate_id pres_inter  vmax_inter
9   10  0   7   1   9.6451E-06  2   97809   23.545
9   10  0   7   1   9.6451E-06  17  100170  13.843
10  3   6   7   1   9.6451E-06  2   96662   31.568
13  22  12  8   1   9.6451E-06  1   94449   48.466
13  22  12  8   1   9.6451E-06  17  96749   30.55
16  13  0   8   1   9.6451E-06  4   98702   19.205
16  13  0   8   1   9.6451E-06  16  98585   18.143
19  27  6   9   1   9.6451E-06  9   98838   20.053

header <- read.table(fname_in, nrows=1)
track <- read.table(fname_in, sep=',', skip=1)
colnames(track) <- c("ID", "day", "month", "year", "hour", "rate", "gate_id", "pres_inter", "vmax_inter")
```

I think I would like to count the occurrence of each gate_id, and also perhaps output the maximum wind per gate (vmax_inter), etc....

Comment: Please provide more details and a reproducible example.  As much as some people like to believe it - we're not wizards and we can't read minds.

Comment: A sample of your data would greatly help

Answer (score 1):

Totally reading your mind, since you provide nothing concrete to go on.  But if `GateID` is one of your data frame columns, you can get the count for each unique `GateID` along with other parameters using `count` from package `plyr`.

```
install.packages("plyr")
library("plyr")
count(mydf, vars = "GateID")
```

See `?count` after installing for further details.

For the 2nd part of your question, see `?aggregate` and consider the formula interface. For example,

```
aggregate(gate_id ~ vmax_inter, data = mydf, FUN = max)
```

or something similar.  By the way, you can combine your two `read.table` steps with 'read.csv`

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but why not just use `table(df$GateID)`?

Comment: `table` would be about the same, but I prefer `count` for it's format.  I'm sure I'm down voted for answering an improperly posed question.  Oh well.

Comment: I would like to include two output columns after frequency that include the **average** vmax_inter per gate_id, and also the **maximum** vmax_inter per gate_id.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have never seen or heard of read.csv.  I am very new to R programming.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you would have to write your own FUN to specify what you want and then use aggregate(..., FUN = myfun).  I tried a quick example and it will need some tweaking, so instead let me suggest `FUN = fivenum` Do `?fivenum` and you'll see what the 5 columns give you.  Then you can subset the resulting data frame so it contains only the values you want. Example: `res <- aggregate(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, FUN = fivenum)`